# Como adicionar ícone de x no check-box

Tags: css, ionic

Preciso acrescentar um `X` no check-box que não está ativo, eu consigo adicionar quando ele fica ativo o `V`. Estou utilizando o `íon Framework` para me auxiliar na estilização. Segue o código do `check`:

```
<li class="item item-checkbox widget uib_w_70 d-margins colorGeral" data-uib="ionic/checkbox" data-ver="0">
   <label class="checkbox">
      <input id="testeeeee" type="checkbox">
   </label>checkbox</li>
```

Este é o icone que preciso:

```
ion-android-close
```

[image: CHECK-BOX ATIVO]
[image: CHECK-BOX DESATIVO]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não tenho experiência nenhuma com Ionic, mas até alguém com mais experiência possa lhe dar uma resposta, fica a dica de como fazer com CSS.

Eu utilizei a seguinte fonte de ícones (talvez seja a mesma do Ionic, mas não encontrei o ícone com o nome que você citou).

- [Ionicons](http://ionicons.com)

O primeiro passo foi pegar o código que eles usam no pseudo elemento para inserir a fonte.

Para isso inspecionei o elemento da fonte e verifiquei o que havia no content dele

[image: Como verificar o pseudo elemento]

Neste caso consegui o seguinte `content: "\f404";` que é o que usamos para adicionar o "×".

Repeti os mesmos passos para pegar o "✔"

O restante é somente estilização.

Segue o código que fiz

```css
.checkbox {
  border: #ccc 1px solid;
  font: 300 1em 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  margin: 1em 0;
  padding: 1em;
}

.checkbox label {
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}

.checkbox input[type="checkbox"] + label::before {
  content: "\f404";
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #e74c3c;
  font-family: "Ionicons";
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: .5em;
}

.checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::before {
  content: "\f3fd";
  background-color: #2ecc71;
}

.checkbox input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" id="checked" checked>
  <label for="checked">Checkbox</label>
</div>

<div class="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" id="unchecked">
  <label for="unchecked">Checkbox</label>
</div>
```

E aqui um Fiddle contendo o mesmo código

[https://jsfiddle.net/Wagner/r55qt2x9](https://jsfiddle.net/Wagner/r55qt2x9/)